# Why is a module removed in the root folder's web.config being used in a subfolder?

Tags: iis-7, web-config

My application has this structure

MyApplication
    -Themes

In my application's webconfig I remove the UrlAuthorization module and add my own:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <remove name="UrlAuthorization" />
  <add name="MyModule" type="MyType, MyNamespace" preCondition="managedHandler" />
</modules>
```

My Theme folder has this webconfig (this is the complete webconfig):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<system.web>
    <pages styleSheetTheme="" validateRequest="false" />
</system.web>
 </configuration>
```

I have this deployed in 3 environments. 2 of them works correctly but in one of them I have the UrlAuthorization module working when I make a request do a file inside the Theme folder.

- I know that the UrlAuthorization is active because I do not get the resource I requested, but an URL /ReturnURl/... path
- The < remove> tag is working because removing it causes the whole request to be redirect to the /ReturnUrl

Is there any reason that may cause this behavior to happen only in this machine?
I deployed all of them and I do not remember making and different task on any of them

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

FYI, it was an issue due to the folders permissions in the file system. I made the environments identical and it worked.